# I cannot send HTML mail using "{{ node.body.value }}"

Tags: rules, 9, mimemail

I use Drupal 9 and the Rules module to send emails when an *Article* node is updated.
I installed the *Mimemail* module and set the formatter to *mimemail*;  all the field are correctly rendered. Only `{{ node.body.value }}` displays the HTML markup in the mail directly.

The rule settings are the following.

```html
Hello, {{node.field_unit}} ！<br>
New Message Alert!<br>
<br>
id：{{ node.field_id }}<br>
mail：{{ node.field_mail }}<br>
type：{{ node.field_type }}<br>
time：{{ node.created }}<br>
subject：{{ node.title }}<br>
content：<br>
{{ node.body.value }}<br>
```

The received email is rendered like in this screenshot.

> [image: the email result]

These are the value stored in the database.

> [image: In the database]

I'm not sure how to solve this.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.value` use `.processed` to get the formatted output:

```
{{ node.body.processed }}
```

Comment: In some circumstances you might have to use a filter to prevent Rules from sanitizing the output:  `{{ node.body.processed | format_text("full_html") }}`

Comment: Hello, I try {{ node.body.processed }}, the tags will show in the mail.
And I try {{ node.body.processed | format_text("full_html") }} it will show an error in logs --->Missing text format: "full_html".

Type filter
Date 2022 7 4 - 11:52
User        admin
Location https://192.168.7.173/node/148/edit?destination=%2Ffeedback
Source https://192.168.7.173/node/148/edit?destination=/feedback
Message Missing text format: "full_html".

But I do enable the full_html format
Do you have any idea how may this occur? Thanks!

Comment: Go to /admin/config/content/formats/manage/full_html - this should exist if you have a filter with the machine name "full_html". If it DOES exist then I don't know why you're getting that error. That error will be generated by the core filter module when a filter plugin with the machine name "full_html" can't be found. It wouldn't hurt to clear your cache ...

Comment: yes I do have the format machine name as full_html... I don't know why either. Anyway thanks for your reply. I'm using business rules instead.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this solution works for me only when I use single quotation marks around `full_html`: `{{ node.body.processed | format_text('full_html') }}`. Just mentioning this in case it will help someone else.